# version of tsc is not the same inside and outside of vscode (ubuntu)

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, version, tsc

If I do a `tsc --version` inside of vscode I get `Version 3.8.3`. If I do it in a separate terminal, I get `Version 4.5.4`.
What is strange to me is that `which tsc` results in an identical path for both alternatives:
`/home/corno/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/bin/tsc`

How can this be? I expected that because the paths are equal, that I should have gotten the same version.

What can be the cause of this?

Comment: I still don't understand what's going on, but if I'm executing the full path (/home/corno/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/bin/tsc) within vscode, it runs the 4.5.4 version. So somehow 'which' is not reporting the correct location of which executable will be run

Comment: Can you specify the file structure of your VSCode workspace, and the cwd each time you make a command (tsc or which)?

Comment: I run those commands in the root of the workspace

Answer (score 0):

I deinstalled vscode, threw its 2 data directories away and reinstalled. This solved the issue.

`~/.vscode` and `~/.config/Code`